# How to color table cell based on content

Tags: php, html, colors, html-table

I"m using the following php code to color different cells in my html table but was wondering if there was a better way of doing this.

```
<?php if($crew['status'] == 'OUT') { ?>
  <td style='text-align:center;font-size:80%;color:red'   ><?php echo $crew['status'] ?></td>
<?php } else if($crew['status'] == 'OPEN') { ?>
  <td style='text-align:center;font-size:80%;color:blue'  ><?php echo $crew['status'] ?></td>
<?php } else if($crew['status'] == 'CONFIRMED') { ?>   
  <td style='text-align:center;font-size:80%;color:green' ><?php echo $crew['status'] ?></td>
<?php } else if($crew['status'] == 'WAITLIST') { ?>   
  <td style='text-align:center;font-size:80%;color:purple'><?php echo $crew['status'] ?></td>
<?php } else  { ?>   
  <td style='text-align:center;font-size:80%;color:orange'>TIMESPAN</td>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty... You should avoid using lots of inline CSS.

You could do something like the following:

```
<style>
#yourtable tr td {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:80%;
}
</style>

<?php 
$colors = [
  'OUT' => 'red',
  'OPEN' => 'blue',
  'CONFIRMED' => 'green',
  'WAITLIST' => 'purple'
];
?>

<?php if (array_key_exists($crew['status'], $colors)): ?>
<td style="color:<?= $colors[$crew['status']]?>"><?= $crew['status'] ?></td>
<?php else: ?>
<td style="color:orange">TIMESPAN</td>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: I like this but why the line $crew['status'] = 'OUT'; ?  I don't think that's needed

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
  <td class="status-<?php echo $crew['status']; ?>><?php echo $crew['status'] ?></td>

  ...

  <style type="text/css">
    td.status {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 80%;
      color: orange;
    }
    td.status-OUT { color: red; }
    td.status-OPEN { color: blue; }
    td.status-CONFIRMED { color: green; }
    td.status-WAITLIST { color: purple; }
  </style>
```